# Incorrect hits.total response value even with index.max_result_window Increased

Tags: elasticsearch

I increased the limit on an index using the setting index.max_result_window in the index _settings document in order to support offset/limit pagination queries with a greater response size. I'm able to make queries against the index with result counts greater than 10,000 (the default), but for some reason, the hits.total value never changes, it always seems to come back as 10,000, even though the actual number of search results returned is greater than this.

Is there any way to get this returned value to represent the actual number of responses rather than just displaying the default value of 10,000, even after index.max_result_window is increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `"track_total_hits": true` in the request

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer your question, this answer would be much more useful for future users if you explain how exactly it should be used and what should be the request structure.